# Visualize Networks Within A City

Tags: gephi

I was curious if it was possible to geographically display networks at a smaller level of geography such as a city.  I've used the geolayout plugin, but it seems to barely recognize the small distinctions in longitude and latitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to scale the graph to an extremely large value (>1000000).